# Strange behaviour on my mac in the past few days. Worried about virus, etc

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I've used this iMac for several years with few problems:

[image]

However, I've experienced strange behaviour in the past few days, and I have no idea what is causing it, so I shall put down what I think might be relevant.

Earlier in the year I installed Virtual Box to use Windows 10. I haven't bothered installing any antivirus software as Win 10 has Windows Defender, and I mostly use the VM for programming purposes only (although I do use my email/facebook inside it sometimes). I use the Guest Additions add on as well. I recently updated Virtual Box to the latest version (Version 5.0.26 r108824) in the past few days.

In the past few days I've had my mouse randomly jumping to the corners of my screen (mostly the top/bottom left, I think, although I've had all corners visited). After it jumps there, it's frozen for about a second before I'm able to move it again. This has happened with increasing regularity up to today — up to twice in a minute. I've tried looking up this issue, but the threads I've found about this are several years old. I can't be sure because I have Virtual Box running most of the time, but it seems these random jumps occur after I've opened Virtual Box. However, they continue after I close it and also when the VM is paused (with Command+P), so I cannot be sure if this isn't just coincidence.

Today, I've had even stranger behaviour with the wifi symbol in the top right of the screen (I'd been using Virtual Box, at the time). In the midst of toggling it on and off, I found that the icon and the words told me that the wifi was off when on, and on when off. However, System Preferences displays the correct state of the wifi at the same time. I've managed to reproduce this bug after restarting my computer (I'm not sure how, though. The wifi displayed normally on startup, but it then somehow switched again...). Putting my computer to sleep and waking it up again fixes it, though.

[image: Wifi1]

[image: Wifi2]

I have no idea what is going on with my mac. My biggest worry is a keylogger. I don't want to reinstall OSX because there are other users on here. Could I have some guidance on what I should do?

However, if it really comes down to it, and reinstalling OSX is my best option, what is the best way of transferring files so that I can ensure any viruses, etc, aren't carried over?

Update:

I've now completely wiped MacKeeper from my system. I can also confirm that it's very likely that the mouse jumping has something to do with Virtual Box. I've had the VM closed for the past hour with no mouse jumping. But after updating to the latest version of Virtual Box (Version 5.1.4 r110228 (Qt5.5.1)), I'm experiencing the mouse jumping frequently while the VM is open (but for some reason it continues after it is closed too).

Second Update:

After restarting my computer again, the mouse began moving erratically as soon as I logged in — so perhaps it isn't related to Virtual Box after all. I really cannot be sure, and I don't have a systematic way to test this out. This seems to occur only when I'm moving my mouse around which was perhaps why I didn't experience anything for that past hour when I wasn't using the mouse as much.

Comment: I'd have another look for MacKeeper using [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) it searches a lot of locations Spotlight won't, though it's not indexed, so it's slower. According to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads 5.1.4 is the latest build, idk if that will make any difference.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks — I've managed to completely get rid of it now. When I check for updates in Virtual Box it tells me I'm running the latest version?

Comment: Are you using a wireless mouse?

Comment: @JamesP It's wired. It's several years old, although I've only picked it back up in the last ~2 months.

Comment: It would be worth trying another mouse to rule out your current one as the source of the problem.